# Launch file for UWSim problem. How do you write the node?

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The below code portion works to launch the default UWSim node, but how do you alter it to open any other scene?

```
 <!-- UWSim Node-->

  <node pkg="uwsim" type="uwsim" name="uwsim" />
```

ROS is not familiar territory for me, but I have worked through the turtlesim and have spent time poking at variations on --configfile /.../scene.xml

Any suggestions on how this works would be appreciated. I don't want to have to ditch this project.

Thanks.
J

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214454/launch-file-for-uwsim-problem.-how-do-you-write-the-node?/) by [jhoban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23329/jhoban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I usually use this code in my launch files:

```
<arg name="scene" default="cirs.xml" />
<node name="uwsim" pkg="uwsim" type="uwsim" args="--configfile $(arg scene)" output="screen" respawn="false" />
```

And launch it like this, using just the name of the scene (stored in  uwsim/data/scenes):

```
roslaunch {package} {launchfile} scene:=shipwreck.xml
```

Hope it works.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jhoban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23329/jhoban/) on 2015-07-24**:
It worked.

Thankyou very much for the information.

J